# How to check if words starts with within the alphabet range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this simple program

```
quote = input("Enter your name : ")
start=0
space_index=quote.find(" ")
while space_index != -1:
   print(quote[start:space_index])
```

I want that whatever word comes out should starts with **a to g**.
I tried the with importing string class and using his ascii_lowercase() function but I still I am not able to figure out how to check if the word starts with the range **a to g** or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [`startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) like so:

```
quote = input("Enter your name : ")
allowed = 'abcdefg'
if any(quote.startswith(x) for x in allowed):
   print('Success!')
```

Alternatively and to make it more flexible you can use this:

```
import string
start = 'a'
end = 'g'
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
allowed = letters[letters.index(start):letters.index(end)+1]  # abcdefg
quote = input("Enter your name : ")

while not any(quote.startswith(x) for x in allowed):
    quote = input("The name is not valid! Please enter another name: ")
print('Success!')
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if i have like range from a-z ? isn't their any way to defined range like startswith(range(a,z)) ?

Comment: @ViralParmar Is that better now?

Comment: Also, if casing is not important, we could use a `quote.lower().startswith(x)`

Comment: @Qrom OP specifically said `lowercase` but yeah, sure. That is up to him.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis really nice work here, I cannot do anything but upvote and congrats

Answer (score 4):

re.match:

```
re.match(r'[A-G, a-g]', yourstringhere)
```

Comment: Thanks! But I dont want to use regular experession.

Comment: @ViralParmar Why not? Simply saying you don't want to use something without compelling reasons is rarely a good idea.

Comment: I know that regular expression and easy to write and effective, but Its just I was trying whether if its possible without using regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `re` module that is simple:

```
import re
quote = input("Enter your name : ")
matches = [s for s in quote.split() if re.match('^[a-g,A-G]', s)]
```

Did you notice this part `[a-g,A-G]`?
You can change it to whatever range you want, like `[a-z]` for only lowercase, `[a-z,A-Z]` for all ascii letters, `[0-9]` for numbers etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test a specific range of letters, you can use the `ord()` function to get the ascii value of the start and end letters of the range, and use `chr()` to get the textual value of the character's ascii vaule:

```
>>> def starts_in_range(string, char_range):
...     start, end = char_range.split('-')
...     ord_char_range = range(ord(start), ord(end) + 1)
...     return ord(string[0]) in ord_char_range

>>> starts_in_range('globe', 'a-g')
True
>>> starts_in_range('butter', 'a-g')
True
>>> starts_in_range('nuts', 'a-g')
False
>>> starts_in_range('kimmy', 'a-g')
False
>>> starts_in_range('dumbo', 'a-g')
True
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: you can simplify your check like so: `return ord(string[0]) in ord_char_range`. That said, I like the *mechanics* of it xD

Comment: That's what I was about to ask xD. I did the same and it worked. But Still I didn't understood the the last line in original program...what is actually happening in last line. I didnt understood "any(chr(char) "

Comment: @ViralParmar I got your back Viral. ;)

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Ah, yes. Thanks. I guess I need to go ahead to bed :P

Answer (score 0):

You where close enaugh thinking in string.ascci, you can do this:

```
import string

a_to_g = string.ascii_lowercase[0:7]

print(a_to_g)
```

> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

```
quote = input("Enter your name : ")

print(quote[0] in a_to_g) 

print(a_to_g)
```

> True

If you want to go more than from a to g, you just change the indexs from the `string.ascii_lowercase`

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: You code would work even if you did not cast the letters to `list`, so don't ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use functions `ord` and `chr` for converting to ascii number and converting number to ascii respectivly

```
quote = input("Enter your name : ")
if qoute[0] in list(map(chr,range(ord('a'),ord('g')+1))):
    #proceed
```